# How to compare UNIX DATA and TIME

Tags: mysql

I have: (this example works)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM messages m
WHERE
  m.create_timestamp > STR_TO_DATE('2016-01-28 05:06:38', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
ORDER BY m.create_timestamp
LIMIT 100;
```

but I have this '2016-01-28 05:06:38' datetime in UNIX FORMAT.
I tried:

```sql
m.create_timestamp > FROM_UNIXTIME(1453946798, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

But this doesn't work.

I want to compare date in UNIX FORMAT: `m.create_timestamp > 1453946798`.
Help please!

Comment: What you have and what you want is unclear. I'm pretty sure everybody who answered you didn't understand the problem you're facing. You should edit your post to get more accurate answers

Comment: If `m.create_timestamp` is a UNIX Timestamp and what you have is a UNIX timestamp, why not comparing the values with a simple: `m.create_timestamp > 1453946798`?  The highest value is the one that is later in time since it's just milliseconds from a given point in time (that I don't recall exactly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNIX format is just the number of milliseconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. So you can just compare the values between them. The highest value will be the point that is later in time.

A simple:

```sql
m.create_timestamp > 1453946798
```

- `> 1453946798` means it's after `2016-01-28 05:06:38`
- `< 1453946798` means it's before `2016-01-28 05:06:38`

Make sure the unix timestamps have the same precision though. Sometimes it's the number of seconds since epoch instead of milliseconds for precision and storage size reasons.

If you have a timestamp in milliseconds to compare with your 1453946798, divide it by 1000 and floor it before comparing the timestamps.

---

To convert a `DATETIME` to a `TIMESTAMP`, you can use the following:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-15 12:00:00');
```

Of course, replace `'2015-01-15 12:00:00'` with the date to convert.

Comment: @axon so what's the type of the column? `DAMETIME`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM messages m
WHERE
m.create_timestamp > FROM_UNIXTIME(create_timestamp)
ORDER BY m.create_timestamp
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: I have only UNIX DATATIME, this: 1453946798

Comment: i want to compare DATETIME in UNIX FORMAT

Comment: @axon Did you try : `m.create_timestamp > FROM_UNIXTIME(1453946798)`?

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat, of course, compare only DATE. TIME is not compared in UNIX FORMAT

Answer (score 0):

I think you want unix_timestamp(); this command will convert a datetime to a unix timestamp: `unix_timestamp('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')`.

Comment: I have 1453946798 unix timestamp already, i need to compare that number. I think, first, convert that and compare like ordinary string date